# Union Type: One or the other failing. Not sure if this is by design or a bug

Tags: typescript

Consider a situation where an object can have *exactly* the `FooBar` or `Baz` interface listed below.

```
interface FooBar {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

interface Baz {
    baz: string;
}
```

It's my understanding that this "one or the other" situation can be handled by creating a union between `FooBar` and `Baz`.

```
type FooBarOrBaz = FooBar | Baz;
```

So far so good...

The issue I'm having is that the following object passes type checking:

```
const x: FooBarOrBaz = {
    foo: 'foo',
    baz: 'foo',
};
```

Is this a bug?

[Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20FooBar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Baz%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FooBarOrBaz%20%3D%20FooBar%20%7C%20Baz%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20FooBarOrBaz%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20'foo'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20'foo'%2C%0D%0A%7D)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even weirder, you can do `const x: FooBarOrBaz = { foo: 123; baz: "foo" }` but you can't do `{ fooz: 123, baz: "foo" }` because `fooz` is an unknown prop... so basically it sees `baz: "foo"` as satisfying `Baz` interface and it sees `foo` as a known prop but it doesn't check its type... this seems hard to justify!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a bug here.

It can be made even more explicit by switching to classes and then using the type narrowing aspects of `instanceof` on union types.

Start with your code, but switched to classes:

```
class FooBar {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

class Baz {
    baz: string;
}

type FooBarOrBaz = FooBar | Baz;
```

Create an instance, as you did - compiles fine.

```
const x: FooBarOrBaz = {
    foo: 'foo',
    baz: 'baz',
}
```

Check if we've got a `FooBar`:

```
if (x instanceof FooBar) {
    console.log("x is a FooBar : (" + x.foo + "," + x.bar + ")");
} else {
    console.log("x is not FooBar must be Baz : " + x.baz);
}
```

This compiles without warnings and prints `x is not FooBar must be Baz : baz`.

Check if we've got a `Baz`:

```
if (x instanceof Baz) {
    console.log("x is a Baz : (" + x.baz + ")");
} else {
    console.log("x is not Baz must be FooBar : " + x.foo + "," + x.bar);
}
```

Also compiles fine, but prints `x is not Baz must be FooBar : foo,undefined`

So either accepting this kind of input is a bug, or allowing it leads to a bug in the type narrowing of the `instanceof` type guard.

Comment: `x instanceof Y` checks if `x` was created using something that gave it a prototype `Y`. Since your x was created as plain object, without using prototypes or class constructors at all, both instanceof should return false - no bug here.

Comment: The bug is that in the `else` branch of the `if( x instanceof Baz)` the compiler assumes that if it isn't a `Baz` it must be a `FooBar` - and so I can access the `x.foo` on it without warning.

Comment: [instanceof type guards are a way of narrowing types using their constructor function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards). For union types, the compiler literally trusts the type guard and can't detect that it's used improperly here. Also [A type is assignable to a union type iff it is assignable to at least one constituent](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14369#issuecomment-283185123). The value assigned to x is structurally compatible with Baz, and excess property foo is not reported as error as it's done for non-union type

Comment: Since the general consensus here seems like this is a bug, I opened an issue for this here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14383

Thanks for the feedback everybody.